# Regex to match defanged URLs

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match URLs which have been defanged within text, but struggling. Ordinarily I'd use regex from CyberChef to catch URLs, like this:

```
([A-Za-z]+://)([-\w]+(?:\.\w[-\w]*)+)(:\d+)?(/[^.!,?;"\x27<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]*(?:[.!,?]+[^.!,?;"\x27<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]+)*)?
```

However this is a bit overkill for my needs and doesn't catch where URLs are defanged with square brackets, examples of matches I'm looking for are:

```
http://www.google.com
hxxp://www[.]google[.]com
hxxp://www.google[.]com
foob://www[.]google.com
```

Regex I've been playing with:

```
([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)[\w]+?\[.?\][\w]+?\[.?\][\w]+
```

But this seems to catch only where the defanging is present. Help appreciated.

Comment: Could you use [**`\w+://\S+`**](https://regex101.com/r/kkULvz/1)?

Comment: @revo simple and effective. nice.

Comment: This may come in handy when defanging URLs: https://pypi.org/project/defang/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A defunged or literal dot may be expressed as `(?:\[\.\]|\.)` so the regex would be

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)?[\w]+?(?:\[\.\]|\.)[\w]+?(?:\[\.\]|\.)[\w]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mtBaeY/2

Comment: very cool. as an update to my question is it possible to also match if the url is not prefix with hxxp:// i.e. just the domain? Note, i know this is not what i asked, but just seeing how easy it is to extend the idea.

Comment: @m0atz, yes, just put `?` after the first group. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: you rock dude :)

Comment: Ah - i thought i could figure out how to account for hxxps://google.com using a ? but its getting the better of me again ha.

Comment: actually think i got it, i made more capturing groups and used ? on those. (?:[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)?([\w]+?(?:\[\.\]|\.))?([\w]+?(?:\[\.\]|\.)[\w]+) Thanks again.

Comment: Lame.  Doesn't match `example.com`.  Not all domain names have 3 parts.